# Analytical tools for collecting website performance metrics, page views, average latency?

Tags: performance, google-analytics, web-analytics, website-metrics

We're looking for analytical tools that collect and graph website metrics...

**What we need...**

- Real-time performance metrics
- Page hits
- average response times, page view latency, etc
- Works in an intranet for performance and load testing scenarios

**What we Don't need**

- Tracking user behavior, etc (we're looking at separate tools for this stuff)

We're most concerned about collecting site performance metrics for optimization and tuning purposes. The tool must work on an intranet for load-testing scenarios as well.

Comment: What are the volumes of simultaneous users ? What type of realtime do you need ? Seconds, minutes, 15 minutes, hour ? What's the prupose of realtime data ? How do you imagine to correlate performance data and application usage if you use 2 different tools for application/performance ? What about the impact of tracking tools on performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no specific experience with it, but [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) could be your man

Answer (score 0):

You can get most of that from the logs of your web server. But i dont know any tool that will read and do the full analisys for you.

I found this one, maybe it could work.

http://www.weblogexpert.com/lite.htm

Comment: There's got to to be tool for aggregating that info from the logs?

Comment: mm i know all the calculations but let me see if i can find some tool that could do it automatically,